# .Net youtube data api. Detect if embedding has been disabled?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am creating a small window form application which will return list of videos based on query. I am using this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet Everything is working fine except for the issue that if embedding is disabled by owner of some video then I am getting an error while trying to play the video that: 
"Watch this video on youtube. Playback on other websites has been disabled by the video onwer".

So now I have two questions

1) Is there any way to play that video?

2) IF anwser of the first question is no then how can I filter those videos whose embedding has been disabled by it's owner. Means I don't want to add those videos in my list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. After exploring the documentation I finally found the solution to filter those videos whose embedding is disabled by the owner.

There is VideoEmbeddable property of YoutubeService.Search.List method which expects Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoEmbeddableEnum  can do the trick.

```
var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.Q = ""; // Replace with your search term.
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            searchListRequest.Type = "video";
            searchListRequest.VideoEmbeddable = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoEmbeddableEnum.True__;
```

Specifying a type "video" only returns video insteal of all  videos, playlists and channels.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) every video has `status.embeddable` property, which you can check in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't find status.embeddable in .Net

Answer (score 0):

The status.embedabble, regardless of language used, is a response anytime one of the methods used in [Videos reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) is successfully called.

So I would suggest using the method list for example. To demonstrate, I place a youtube video in this [videos.list Try-it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#usage) and place "status" as part parameter.

And true enough I get the embedabble status:

```
"items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/7NFYOO88j54fU9aKM8MsjN4zPro\"",
      "id": "kIBdpFJyFkc",
      "status": {
        "uploadStatus": "processed",
        "privacyStatus": "public",
        "license": "youtube",
        "embeddable": true,
        "publicStatsViewable": true
      }
    }
  ]
```